FastAPI Insert Performance: 1-2 ms Per Insert - Is This Normal?
I’m building a scalable FastAPI application with the goal of handling more than 10,000 requests per second (RPS). My application is quite complex. However, I’ve identified a significant bottleneck in scaling: each individual insert operation takes about 1 to 2 milliseconds of CPU time.
This CPU time means that a single worker is heavily capped, limiting my full stack application to around 300 RPS for endpoints involving multiple inserts with one pod / worker. As a result, I need to scale up a lot of workers to achieve higher RPS, which seems inefficient.
Again the problem here is not so much the time it takes on the db side, I am not too concerned about latency in my use case, but the cpu time limiting scaling.
I created a simplified reproducible example. It shows that a single insert takes around 1 to 2 milliseconds. I’m trying to understand if this performance is normal for FastAPI, or if there’s something wrong with my setup. I have seen benchmarks showing better performance, so I’m wondering if there’s any optimization potential.
Here’s the simplified code for the insert operation:
app.py
import time
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

from fastapi import FastAPI
from sqlalchemy import AsyncAdaptedQueuePool, text
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

db_username = "****"
db_password = "****"
host = "****"

async def setup_database():
    dsn = f"postgresql+asyncpg://{db_username}:{db_password}@{host}:5432/postgres"
    engine = create_async_engine(
        dsn,
        pool_size=20,
        poolclass=AsyncAdaptedQueuePool,
    )
    return sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession)


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # Setup the database connection pool
    app.state.db_session = await setup_database()
    yield
    # Close the database connection pool
    await app.state.db_session.close()


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.get("/test-insert")
async def test_insert():
    start_time = time.time()
    start_cpu_time = time.process_time()

    insert_query = text("INSERT INTO simple_text (text) VALUES (:text) RETURNING id")
    params = {"text": "Test"}

    async with app.state.db_session.begin() as sess:
        result = await sess.execute(insert_query, params)
        text_id = result.scalar_one()
        await sess.commit()

    end_time = time.time()
    end_cpu_time = time.process_time()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    cpu_duration = end_cpu_time - start_cpu_time

    print(
        f"Test Insert: {duration:.6f} seconds, CPU time: {cpu_duration:.6f} CPU seconds"
    )

    return {"id": text_id, "duration": duration, "cpu_duration": cpu_duration}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

Dockerfile
# Use an official Python 3.12 runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.12-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install the dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Expose port 8000 to the outside world
EXPOSE 8000

# Command to run the FastAPI application
CMD ["uvicorn", "app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

requirements.txt
fastapi
uvicorn[standard]
sqlalchemy
asyncpg

I noticed that if I bypass sqlalchemy and use asyncpg directly using this code:
async def setup_database():
    return await asyncpg.create_pool(
        user=db_username,
        password=db_password,
        database="postgres",
        host=host,
        port=5432,
        min_size=20,
        max_size=20,
    )

@app.get("/test-insert")
async def test_insert():
    start_time = time.time()
    start_cpu_time = time.process_time()

    insert_query = """
                INSERT INTO simple_text (text)
                VALUES ($1)
                RETURNING id
            """
    params = ("Test",)
    async with app.state.connection_pool.acquire() as connection:
        text_id = await connection.fetchval(insert_query, *params)

    end_time = time.time()
    end_cpu_time = time.process_time()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    cpu_duration = end_cpu_time - start_cpu_time

    print(
        f"Test Insert: {duration:.6f} seconds, CPU time: {cpu_duration:.6f} CPU seconds"
    )

    return {"id": text_id, "duration": duration, "cpu_duration": cpu_duration}

Which gives an average cpu time 0.0004 which is about 3x improvement so that's good. Is that the very minimum performance? And is this gap to be expected between sqlalchemy and asyncpg?
For context I set up a postgresql db with a table simple_text being made of just a primary key id and a character column text.
I am using a macbook pro M3 with colima and rosetta (but this perf problem seems to be happening on my gcp k8 set up that uses linux pods).
Thanks for any help!

Is the CPU time spent in the database or in your Python code? What is the network latency between application and database?

Hi Laurenz, thanks for looking into this. The CPU time is the python code one. Let's assume that I don't care about latency, and I am solely interested in how many RPS can get done, so the main focus is CPU of python.
Not sure the latency is relevant for this then, but correct me if I am wrong.

Have you tried repeated inserts to see if that has an affect?  Ie. the query might be cached, a db connection might be created to fulfill the request from the pool, etc.

Also, are you trying to achieve 10000 individual inserts a second?

Hey Ian thanks for helping!


Yes I tried repeated and indeed it divises by 10x. But the time communicated in the post are the times of the repeated inserts indeed.


Yes - I know it would be better to batch but in that use case, there are 10000 frontend interacting with my db and I would want to process them individually. But again it can take longer for the insert to actually process, I only care about CPU time of python here.



I think also commit is implied when using begin() so you can remove the trailing commit().

Also, the benchmarks you link seem to be batched updates per request which will reduce latency right?  Part of the problem is getting the connection, returning the connection, caching, etc.  ALL for one single statement.

I don't think so looking at this: benchmark it seems like for one update per request they reached 10k request with orm and 40k without. They linked their code here repo

Just noticed that they are using 14 workers on their benchmark with 14 cpus.
So we can expect their results to be ~14x more RPS. Which might explain the difference...

I'm running this script locally via docker between a docker app container and a docker postgresql db container.  It tries to use as little sqlalchemy as possible.  The first insert is always the slowest and then the subsequent inserts are faster.  I think there is some sort initialization happening, maybe query caching or something like that?
import os
import asyncio
import time

from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    String,
    Integer
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import (
    insert,
    select
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    declarative_base,
)
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine
#, async_sessionmaker, AsyncSession


MAX_OVERFLOW = 20


POOL_SIZE=10


def get_engine(env):
    db_uri = f"postgresql+asyncpg://{env['DB_USER']}:{env['DB_PASSWORD']}@{env['DB_HOST']}:{env['DB_PORT']}/{env['DB_NAME']}"
    print (db_uri)
    return create_async_engine(db_uri, pool_size=POOL_SIZE, max_overflow=MAX_OVERFLOW) #, echo=True, echo_pool='debug')

Base = declarative_base()


class SimpleText(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'simple_texts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = Column(String)


async def main():

    engine = get_engine(os.environ)
    #dbsession_maker = async_sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession)

    async with engine.begin() as connection:
        await connection.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
    runs = 100
    q = insert(SimpleText.__table__).returning(SimpleText.__table__.c.id)
    for _ in range(runs):
        start_time = time.time()
        start_cpu_time = time.process_time()
        # get a connection from pool, begin, execute insert, commit return connection to pool
        async with engine.begin() as conn:
            result = await conn.execute(q, dict(text='Test'))
            text_id = result.scalar_one()
        end_time = time.time()
        end_cpu_time = time.process_time()
        duration = end_time - start_time
        cpu_duration = end_cpu_time - start_cpu_time
        print(f"Test Insert: {duration:.6f} seconds, CPU time: {cpu_duration:.6f} CPU seconds for {text_id}")
    q2 = select(1)
    for _ in range(runs):
        start_time = time.time()
        start_cpu_time = time.process_time()
        # get a connection from pool, begin, execute insert, commit return connection to pool
        async with engine.begin() as conn:
            result = await conn.execute(q2)
            text_id = result.scalar_one()
        end_time = time.time()
        end_cpu_time = time.process_time()
        duration = end_time - start_time
        cpu_duration = end_cpu_time - start_cpu_time

        print(f"Test Select: {duration:.6f} seconds, CPU time: {cpu_duration:.6f} CPU seconds for {text_id}")
    await engine.dispose()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (asyncio.run(main()))


Test Insert: 0.002104 seconds, CPU time: 0.000933 CPU seconds for 1
Test Insert: 0.001487 seconds, CPU time: 0.000441 CPU seconds for 2
Test Insert: 0.001614 seconds, CPU time: 0.000562 CPU seconds for 3
Test Insert: 0.001487 seconds, CPU time: 0.000458 CPU seconds for 4
Test Insert: 0.001285 seconds, CPU time: 0.000416 CPU seconds for 5
Test Insert: 0.001472 seconds, CPU time: 0.000428 CPU seconds for 6
Test Insert: 0.001742 seconds, CPU time: 0.000643 CPU seconds for 7
Test Insert: 0.001580 seconds, CPU time: 0.000490 CPU seconds for 8
Test Insert: 0.001225 seconds, CPU time: 0.000378 CPU seconds for 9
Test Insert: 0.001395 seconds, CPU time: 0.000396 CPU seconds for 10
Test Insert: 0.001421 seconds, CPU time: 0.000385 CPU seconds for 11
Test Insert: 0.001438 seconds, CPU time: 0.000399 CPU seconds for 12
Test Insert: 0.001386 seconds, CPU time: 0.000519 CPU seconds for 13
Test Insert: 0.001488 seconds, CPU time: 0.000388 CPU seconds for 14
Test Insert: 0.001564 seconds, CPU time: 0.000427 CPU seconds for 15
Test Insert: 0.001475 seconds, CPU time: 0.000364 CPU seconds for 16
Test Insert: 0.001680 seconds, CPU time: 0.000440 CPU seconds for 17
Test Insert: 0.001473 seconds, CPU time: 0.000363 CPU seconds for 18
Test Insert: 0.001635 seconds, CPU time: 0.000493 CPU seconds for 19
Test Insert: 0.001481 seconds, CPU time: 0.000380 CPU seconds for 20
Test Insert: 0.001571 seconds, CPU time: 0.000373 CPU seconds for 21
Test Insert: 0.001459 seconds, CPU time: 0.000367 CPU seconds for 22
Test Insert: 0.001418 seconds, CPU time: 0.000365 CPU seconds for 23
Test Insert: 0.001467 seconds, CPU time: 0.000380 CPU seconds for 24
Test Insert: 0.001886 seconds, CPU time: 0.000598 CPU seconds for 25
Test Insert: 0.001701 seconds, CPU time: 0.000528 CPU seconds for 26
Test Insert: 0.001475 seconds, CPU time: 0.000367 CPU seconds for 27
Test Insert: 0.001461 seconds, CPU time: 0.000367 CPU seconds for 28
Test Insert: 0.001590 seconds, CPU time: 0.000365 CPU seconds for 29
Test Insert: 0.001476 seconds, CPU time: 0.000377 CPU seconds for 30
Test Insert: 0.001531 seconds, CPU time: 0.000426 CPU seconds for 31
Test Insert: 0.001510 seconds, CPU time: 0.000418 CPU seconds for 32
Test Insert: 0.001650 seconds, CPU time: 0.000420 CPU seconds for 33
Test Insert: 0.001448 seconds, CPU time: 0.000357 CPU seconds for 34
Test Insert: 0.001596 seconds, CPU time: 0.000463 CPU seconds for 35
Test Insert: 0.001445 seconds, CPU time: 0.000352 CPU seconds for 36
Test Insert: 0.001747 seconds, CPU time: 0.000475 CPU seconds for 37
Test Insert: 0.001479 seconds, CPU time: 0.000418 CPU seconds for 38
Test Insert: 0.001417 seconds, CPU time: 0.000403 CPU seconds for 39
Test Insert: 0.001364 seconds, CPU time: 0.000350 CPU seconds for 40
Test Insert: 0.001501 seconds, CPU time: 0.000364 CPU seconds for 41
Test Insert: 0.001435 seconds, CPU time: 0.000406 CPU seconds for 42
Test Insert: 0.001385 seconds, CPU time: 0.000354 CPU seconds for 43
Test Insert: 0.001358 seconds, CPU time: 0.000354 CPU seconds for 44
Test Insert: 0.001256 seconds, CPU time: 0.000421 CPU seconds for 45
Test Insert: 0.001524 seconds, CPU time: 0.000465 CPU seconds for 46
Test Insert: 0.001368 seconds, CPU time: 0.000355 CPU seconds for 47
Test Insert: 0.001536 seconds, CPU time: 0.000463 CPU seconds for 48
Test Insert: 0.001168 seconds, CPU time: 0.000353 CPU seconds for 49
Test Insert: 0.001356 seconds, CPU time: 0.000357 CPU seconds for 50
Test Insert: 0.001600 seconds, CPU time: 0.000535 CPU seconds for 51
Test Insert: 0.001351 seconds, CPU time: 0.000348 CPU seconds for 52
Test Insert: 0.001511 seconds, CPU time: 0.000361 CPU seconds for 53
Test Insert: 0.001348 seconds, CPU time: 0.000346 CPU seconds for 54
Test Insert: 0.001525 seconds, CPU time: 0.000464 CPU seconds for 55
Test Insert: 0.001378 seconds, CPU time: 0.000363 CPU seconds for 56
Test Insert: 0.001368 seconds, CPU time: 0.000506 CPU seconds for 57
Test Insert: 0.001432 seconds, CPU time: 0.000398 CPU seconds for 58
Test Insert: 0.001411 seconds, CPU time: 0.000361 CPU seconds for 59
Test Insert: 0.001524 seconds, CPU time: 0.000366 CPU seconds for 60
Test Insert: 0.001394 seconds, CPU time: 0.000369 CPU seconds for 61
Test Insert: 0.001468 seconds, CPU time: 0.000369 CPU seconds for 62
Test Insert: 0.001485 seconds, CPU time: 0.000387 CPU seconds for 63
Test Insert: 0.001814 seconds, CPU time: 0.000497 CPU seconds for 64
Test Insert: 0.001583 seconds, CPU time: 0.000393 CPU seconds for 65
Test Insert: 0.001458 seconds, CPU time: 0.000354 CPU seconds for 66
Test Insert: 0.001641 seconds, CPU time: 0.000422 CPU seconds for 67
Test Insert: 0.001584 seconds, CPU time: 0.000354 CPU seconds for 68
Test Insert: 0.001736 seconds, CPU time: 0.000562 CPU seconds for 69
Test Insert: 0.001616 seconds, CPU time: 0.000465 CPU seconds for 70
Test Insert: 0.001445 seconds, CPU time: 0.000341 CPU seconds for 71
Test Insert: 0.001741 seconds, CPU time: 0.000467 CPU seconds for 72
Test Insert: 0.001421 seconds, CPU time: 0.000339 CPU seconds for 73
Test Insert: 0.001463 seconds, CPU time: 0.000362 CPU seconds for 74
Test Insert: 0.001460 seconds, CPU time: 0.000362 CPU seconds for 75
Test Insert: 0.001579 seconds, CPU time: 0.000358 CPU seconds for 76
Test Insert: 0.001470 seconds, CPU time: 0.000363 CPU seconds for 77
Test Insert: 0.001493 seconds, CPU time: 0.000382 CPU seconds for 78
Test Insert: 0.001664 seconds, CPU time: 0.000508 CPU seconds for 79
Test Insert: 0.002211 seconds, CPU time: 0.000773 CPU seconds for 80
Test Insert: 0.001479 seconds, CPU time: 0.000385 CPU seconds for 81
Test Insert: 0.001788 seconds, CPU time: 0.000592 CPU seconds for 82
Test Insert: 0.001588 seconds, CPU time: 0.000465 CPU seconds for 83
Test Insert: 0.002297 seconds, CPU time: 0.000756 CPU seconds for 84
Test Insert: 0.002192 seconds, CPU time: 0.000848 CPU seconds for 85
Test Insert: 0.002189 seconds, CPU time: 0.000884 CPU seconds for 86
Test Insert: 0.002125 seconds, CPU time: 0.000862 CPU seconds for 87
Test Insert: 0.002239 seconds, CPU time: 0.000856 CPU seconds for 88
Test Insert: 0.002166 seconds, CPU time: 0.000886 CPU seconds for 89
Test Insert: 0.002140 seconds, CPU time: 0.000863 CPU seconds for 90
Test Insert: 0.002122 seconds, CPU time: 0.000854 CPU seconds for 91
Test Insert: 0.002249 seconds, CPU time: 0.000869 CPU seconds for 92
Test Insert: 0.002133 seconds, CPU time: 0.000853 CPU seconds for 93
Test Insert: 0.002151 seconds, CPU time: 0.000868 CPU seconds for 94
Test Insert: 0.002188 seconds, CPU time: 0.000904 CPU seconds for 95
Test Insert: 0.002223 seconds, CPU time: 0.000842 CPU seconds for 96
Test Insert: 0.002281 seconds, CPU time: 0.001010 CPU seconds for 97
Test Insert: 0.001583 seconds, CPU time: 0.000564 CPU seconds for 98
Test Insert: 0.002140 seconds, CPU time: 0.000791 CPU seconds for 99
Test Insert: 0.002304 seconds, CPU time: 0.000834 CPU seconds for 100
Test Select: 0.001737 seconds, CPU time: 0.001505 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000986 seconds, CPU time: 0.000842 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.001123 seconds, CPU time: 0.000919 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.001030 seconds, CPU time: 0.000859 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.001019 seconds, CPU time: 0.000850 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.001010 seconds, CPU time: 0.000847 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.001083 seconds, CPU time: 0.000918 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.001001 seconds, CPU time: 0.000844 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.001032 seconds, CPU time: 0.000841 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.001014 seconds, CPU time: 0.000841 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.001068 seconds, CPU time: 0.000862 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000598 seconds, CPU time: 0.000504 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000447 seconds, CPU time: 0.000348 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000439 seconds, CPU time: 0.000347 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000449 seconds, CPU time: 0.000353 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000447 seconds, CPU time: 0.000338 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000438 seconds, CPU time: 0.000339 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000445 seconds, CPU time: 0.000347 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000453 seconds, CPU time: 0.000342 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000440 seconds, CPU time: 0.000339 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000435 seconds, CPU time: 0.000340 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000438 seconds, CPU time: 0.000339 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000447 seconds, CPU time: 0.000349 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000437 seconds, CPU time: 0.000342 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000438 seconds, CPU time: 0.000340 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000432 seconds, CPU time: 0.000339 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000461 seconds, CPU time: 0.000352 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000440 seconds, CPU time: 0.000341 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000437 seconds, CPU time: 0.000339 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000457 seconds, CPU time: 0.000339 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000456 seconds, CPU time: 0.000336 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000466 seconds, CPU time: 0.000339 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000485 seconds, CPU time: 0.000355 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000497 seconds, CPU time: 0.000384 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000444 seconds, CPU time: 0.000344 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000441 seconds, CPU time: 0.000335 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000415 seconds, CPU time: 0.000330 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000439 seconds, CPU time: 0.000340 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000426 seconds, CPU time: 0.000334 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000429 seconds, CPU time: 0.000338 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000423 seconds, CPU time: 0.000333 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000424 seconds, CPU time: 0.000337 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000423 seconds, CPU time: 0.000335 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000434 seconds, CPU time: 0.000347 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000450 seconds, CPU time: 0.000345 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000433 seconds, CPU time: 0.000337 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000432 seconds, CPU time: 0.000336 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000431 seconds, CPU time: 0.000337 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000432 seconds, CPU time: 0.000339 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000426 seconds, CPU time: 0.000335 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000434 seconds, CPU time: 0.000341 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000431 seconds, CPU time: 0.000339 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000446 seconds, CPU time: 0.000352 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000449 seconds, CPU time: 0.000340 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000435 seconds, CPU time: 0.000339 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000433 seconds, CPU time: 0.000338 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000431 seconds, CPU time: 0.000335 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000433 seconds, CPU time: 0.000336 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000428 seconds, CPU time: 0.000335 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000428 seconds, CPU time: 0.000338 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000430 seconds, CPU time: 0.000338 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000441 seconds, CPU time: 0.000348 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000450 seconds, CPU time: 0.000340 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000436 seconds, CPU time: 0.000340 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000434 seconds, CPU time: 0.000339 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000435 seconds, CPU time: 0.000339 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000433 seconds, CPU time: 0.000338 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000430 seconds, CPU time: 0.000337 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000432 seconds, CPU time: 0.000341 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000437 seconds, CPU time: 0.000346 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000443 seconds, CPU time: 0.000342 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000431 seconds, CPU time: 0.000337 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000431 seconds, CPU time: 0.000338 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000441 seconds, CPU time: 0.000350 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000446 seconds, CPU time: 0.000354 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000432 seconds, CPU time: 0.000339 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000430 seconds, CPU time: 0.000338 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000429 seconds, CPU time: 0.000337 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000432 seconds, CPU time: 0.000340 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000455 seconds, CPU time: 0.000351 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000443 seconds, CPU time: 0.000338 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000432 seconds, CPU time: 0.000336 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000435 seconds, CPU time: 0.000339 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000434 seconds, CPU time: 0.000340 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000436 seconds, CPU time: 0.000340 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000428 seconds, CPU time: 0.000336 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000427 seconds, CPU time: 0.000337 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000432 seconds, CPU time: 0.000341 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000452 seconds, CPU time: 0.000351 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000441 seconds, CPU time: 0.000337 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000431 seconds, CPU time: 0.000334 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000429 seconds, CPU time: 0.000337 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000434 seconds, CPU time: 0.000340 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000432 seconds, CPU time: 0.000337 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000427 seconds, CPU time: 0.000337 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000428 seconds, CPU time: 0.000339 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000427 seconds, CPU time: 0.000336 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000452 seconds, CPU time: 0.000351 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000439 seconds, CPU time: 0.000336 CPU seconds for 1
Test Select: 0.000431 seconds, CPU time: 0.000336 CPU seconds for 1


Yes that's what I observed too.
First insert is always 10x time slower than the rest. I think query caching indeed.
Not a problem for me as what matter is mostly the average time not the first one. But even with this it seems too slow.
The time you got are similar with the ones I had using directly asyncpg. They still cap at ~2000 RPS (if 0.0005s per request)

Good to see that your implentation got that performance while still using sqlalchemy tho

The amount of time processing the request itself and network latency is all significantly more than that insert though right?

Here I am not using the orm, I just am using the connection pool and then using core by using the table off the ORM model.  I wanted to see what was fastest with sqlalchemy.  Or if something in the ORM/session was slowing things down.

My main constrain is RPS, not really time.
So I am looking at CPU time cause that limit RPS.
For example if because of latency and db processing time the query takes 2s to come back, but it only takes 0.0001s CPU time on my python code, in theory I could handle 10,000 RPS, it is just that their answer would arrive with a 2s latency. I don't mind about the latency as long as I can serve 10,000 frontend per second in average. Let me know if not clear

I see, that makes sense.  I added a select(1) and it seems that insert is slower but it isn't that much slower.

If the rime is spent in the database, try to use auto_explain with auto_explain.log_analyze = on and auto_explain.log_buffers = on to get the execution plan from a slow execution.
